# Cache error in Grails 2.4.. application from 2.2.1 to 2.4.0 and getting below exception

Tags: grails-2.4

I am trying to use application to upgrade from 2.2.1 to 2.4.0 and now I'm getting the exception below. Could someone please help?

> at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)    at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
>     at